# Memory management in iOS , Simulator vs idevice gives different result

Tags: ios, iphone, memory-management, ios7

i am downloading images from a server, this is my code.

```
-(void) DownloadImages
{
   NSLog(@"Images count to download %lu",(unsigned long)[productID count]); // about 3000
   if ([productID count] > 0)
   {
       // Document Directory
       NSString *myDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
       for (i = 0; i < [productID count]; i++)
       {
       @autoreleasepool      // is this right of use autoreleasepool???
       {
           @autoreleasepool      
           {
               [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(UpdateUI) withObject:nil];
           }
           NSLog(@"image no %d", i);
          NSString *imageURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://serverPath/%@/OnlineSale/images/products/%@img.jpg",clientSite,[productID objectAtIndex:i]];
           UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageURL]]];
           // Reference path
           NSString *imagePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@img.jpg",myDirectory,[productID objectAtIndex:i]];
          NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0f)];
          [imageData writeToFile:imagePath atomically:YES];   
        }
     }
      NSLog(@"Downloading images completed...");
  }
```

}

**EDIT:** this is UpdateUI method

```
 -(void) UpdateUI
 {
    spinner.hidden = NO;
[spinner startAnimating];
    progressCounter.hidden = NO;
    status.text = @"Synchronising Product Images...";
    progressCounter.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d / %lu", i,(unsigned long)[productID count]];
 }
```

while processing this, when i am in **simulator** the maximum memory used is: 
on more than 1500 images download.

[image]

but testing on iPad, the maximum memory is reached to **106.9 MB** and app crashed with this  message, just after 500 images download:

[image]

and screen shows this message:
[image]

i am stuck on this point from last two days, after scratching my head don't find any solution. please help me on this issue..

**Edit:**
using autoreleasedpool way is right or not???

Comment: When you use `performSelectorInBackground` you have to setup your own `NSAutoreleasePool` for the background thread. If not it causes memory leaks. This is not recommended way. You should instead use `NSOperation` and queue or GCD blocks for background processing needs.

Comment: As for the difference you are observing, you should always rely on the real device for memory/performance in general. Simulator runs on your mac hardware and does not 100% replicate the device behaviour.

Comment: @Amar will you please give me the idea of NSAutoreleasePool. how to use it.? and if it is necessary while i am using ARC?

Comment: is this right approach or not?

Comment: @autoreleasepool { [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(UpdateUI) withObject:nil]; }

Comment: @Zaibi https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmAutoreleasePools.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I would suggest enclosing the whole for loop block inside of `@autoreleasepool`. It would look like this:

```
   for (i = 0; i < [productID count]; i++)
   {
     @autoreleasepool      // is this right of use autoreleasepool???
     {
        [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(UpdateUI) withObject:nil];
         NSLog(@"image no %d", i);
         NSString *imageURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://serverPath/%@/OnlineSale/images/products/%@img.jpg",clientSite,[productID objectAtIndex:i]];
         UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageURL]]];
         // Reference path
         NSString *imagePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@img.jpg",myDirectory,[productID objectAtIndex:i]];
         NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0f)];
         [imageData writeToFile:imagePath atomically:YES];   
      }
   }
```

If what you tried to accomplish with your `@autoreleasepool` block was handling memory allocated in `updateUI`, that is not the right approach. You should instead enclose `updateUI` body inside of `@autoreleasepool`.

I would also suggest to post the content of `updateUI`; you could even comment that call out and see whether the download-only is causing the memory issue.

More generally, it seems pretty suspicious to me that you are updating the UI on a background thread. UI should be only updated on the main thread, as a general practice. (But without seeing `updateUI` definition, I cannot really say if this is ok or not).

About the different results you get with a device or the simulator, this is "normal". The simulator is totally unreliable when it come to memory handling, you could also detect leaks with the simulator that are not there on a device.

EDIT:

As an easy patch, try with this approach:

```
for (i = 0; i < [productID count]; i++)
   {
      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        [self UpdateUI];

         NSLog(@"image no %d", i);
        NSString *imageURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://serverPath/%@/OnlineSale/images/products/%@img.jpg",clientSite,[productID objectAtIndex:i]];
         UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageURL]]];
         // Reference path
         NSString *imagePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@img.jpg",myDirectory,[productID objectAtIndex:i]];
        NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0f)];
        [imageData writeToFile:imagePath atomically:YES];   
      });
 }
```

As you'll notice, I am dispatching each step in the loop individually. In this way, the mail loop will be able to update the UI. Notice that this implementation is not optimal, since `dataWithContentsOfURL` will take a little to execute (since it entails a network access) and should not be executed on the main thread (but you were doing it already like this). That should be dispatched on a background queue.

Comment: and i already set the @autoreleasepool as you suggested, but the bad thing is this i don't have my iPad right now to test. :(

Comment: if i simply call this method as : [self UpdateUI]; it is not working, that why using background thread

Comment: see my edit, and when you get your iPad back, try it out. BTW: I was not suggesting to call `updateUI` individually, but to comment it out (not execute it) -- but given its content, I do not think it is the problem. The problem is you are executing too many ops in a loop on the main thread.

Comment: thanks , as soon as i check it on my iPad, will inform you the results

Comment: its okay after clean project

Comment: this is NSLog result: 2014-06-06 19:34:15.062 Agent[1226:90b] Images count to download 2934
2014-06-06 19:34:46.708 Agent[1226:90b] Downloading images completed...
2014-06-06 19:34:46.771 Agent[1226:90b] image no 2934
2014-06-06 19:34:46.797 Agent[1226:90b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 2934 beyond bounds [0 .. 2933]'
*** First throw call stack:

Comment: that is hard to explain: you should not reach index 2934 if `[productID count]` is 2934... on the other hand, are you checking into the app directory in order to say that no file is there?

Comment: the for loop start and end , it takes just 30 seconds.

Comment: never enter in the parentheses of dispatch queue method

Comment: just checked the app directory , there is nothing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55210/discussion-between-zaibi-and-sergio).

Comment: will you please update your answer with @autoreleasepool inside the for loop, it worked for me. so that i can accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

You should use more appropriate method for fetching Image data.
I suggest you to try [NSURLDownload](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLDownload.html) class.

Alternatively you could use one of popular 3rd party networking framework like [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)